# How to reference SVG elements inside iframe using CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, iframe

I am trying to style elements of SVG using CSS. I used iframe in my index.js file to reference my SVG, and the SVG displays fine. However, my CSS styling didn't apply as it would have had I just copy/pasted the SVG contents into my index.js. The contents are stored under an object #document. How do you reference iframe contents using CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an `<iframe>` or an `<object>`? Your title says the former, but your questions suggests the latter.

Assuming you really mean an `<iframe>`. Then the answer is: you can't.  CSS does not work over document boundaries.  So you can't style the contents of an iframe from the page that contains the iframe.  The content of the iframe is a separate file (the SVG file).

If you want to style the SVG, then you will need to put the CSS in the SVG (using a `<style>` element), or reference the CSS file using the XML way of including style sheets:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="common.css"?>
```

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/

Comment: That they use an <object> or an <iframe> doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your svg is on the **same domain**, you could append a stylesheet after loading via js:

```
let svgIframe = document.querySelector('.svgIframe');
if(svgIframe){
svgIframe.addEventListener("load",function(e){  
    let svgDoc = svgIframe.contentDocument;
    let iframeSvg = svgDoc.querySelector('svg');
    let css = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "style");
    css.textContent = 'path{fill:red;}';
    iframeSvg.appendChild(css);
});
}
```